# Type of light that is not visible to human eye but only visible to cameras?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, camera

We are trying to project a grid on a surface and are trying to find the best type of light that would be invisible to the naked eye but could be captured by a camera.

The light should be uniquely colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that color is an aspect of human interpretation, it can't really *"be uniquely colored"*. However, from some of the research I've seen, cameras tend to be sensitive to IR types of light, though they often have added digital filters to remove IR light from images.

So, my answer on this is that it would depend on the camera system. It could be represented by any color, or could just show as black or white or a darker shade of red or lighter shade of violet. Or any other color you choose in post-editing.

**UPDATE**
As far as a light emission that will blind (or partially blind) a camera, the only things I know of are based on intensity. For example, a light source that is super bright causes blow-out in images, also lasers (certain types) focused directly on a cameras lens can cause blow-out and potentially damage. However, we come to a head at the point *"invisible to the human eye."* That is because the vast majority of cameras in circulation are designed to replicate the human eye. Ergo they add a digital filter to remove IR upon image processing. From my understanding, any wavelength that is outside the visible spectrum is ignored in one way or another.

With all that said, it is **possible** that some magical wavelength will do what your describing on **a camera**, however it becomes exponentially less likely with each new camera and model revision. So to that degree, I'd say *yes, it is too "field of dreams."*

Comment: Thank you.  This helps.

How about thinking from the perspective of a "privacy screen" where a light emitted around some object is only picked up by any camera and not human eye and so any video/picture of the object itself is useless. 

Is that too field of dreams?

Comment: @vr00n Updated.

Comment: @kyle_enginner epic. thank you kind sir.  Epic deductions.

The idea is basically similar in motivation to a faraday cage although in this case the cage would have to be invisible and be created by some form emitted light that is not-facing the observer.